# Type Error while running Keras in Azure Machine Learning Service

Tags: azure, keras, azure-machine-learning-service

While running a `keras` inferencing pipeline using Azure Machine Learning Service, I am getting the error:

> `TypeError`: `float()` argument must be a string or a number, not
> `azureml.dataprep.native.DataPrepError`

Comment: can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: hi Dennis, can you send us your code and full stacktrace for investigation? thanks